# How to limit the approve action only for the manager of team

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I'm using odoo11 and i have installed a custom module to calculate the overtime, i've many team leaders, each team leader has a number of employee.

I want to limit the approve action for the manager in a way every manager approve request of his own employees only.

I have override the approve action to verify if the person who's gone approve is his manager or not but always it allows any manager to approve all the requests. Here is code :

overtime.py

```
class BtHrOvertime(models.Model):
_name = "bt.hr.overtime"
_description = "Bt Hr Overtime"
_rec_name = 'employee_id'
_order = 'id desc'

employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee")
manager_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', string='Manager')
start_date = fields.Datetime('Date check in')
end_date = fields.Datetime('Date check out')
overtime_hours = fields.Float('Overtime Hours')
notes = fields.Text(string='Notes')
state = fields.Selection([('draft', 'Draft'), ('confirm', 'Waiting for Approval'), ('refuse', 'Refused'),
                          ('validate', 'Approved'), ('cancel', 'Cancelled')], default='draft', copy=False)
attendance_id = fields.Many2one('hr.attendance', string='Attendance')
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='User', related='employee_id.user_id', related_sudo=True,
                          compute_sudo=True, store=True, default=lambda self: self.env.uid, readonly=True)
parent_id = fields.Many2one('bt.hr.overtime', string='Parent', copy=False)

@api.multi
def action_approve(self):
    if (self.employee_id.parent_id.user_id.id != uid):
        raise exceptions.UserError(_('You cannot approve.'))
    elif  self.attendance_id.check_in and self.attendance_id.check_out:
            start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.attendance_id.check_in, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
            end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.attendance_id.check_out, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT)
            difference = end_date - start_date
            hour_diff = str(difference).split(':')[0]
            min_diff = str(difference).split(':')[1]
            tot_diff = hour_diff + '.' + min_diff
            actual_working_hours = float(tot_diff)
            for record in self:
                if actual_working_hours > 9:
                    record.overtime_hours = actual_working_hours - 9
                    record.start_date = record.attendance_id.check_in
                    record.end_date = record.attendance_id.check_out
                else:
                    record.overtime_hours = 0
                    record.start_date = record.attendance_id.check_in
                    record.end_date = record.attendance_id.check_out
    return self.write({'state': 'validate'})
```

Comment: In the above code where did you checking that who's gone approve is the manager of that employee ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code or checking:

```
if (self.employee_id.parent_id.user_id.id != self.env.user.id):
    raise exceptions.UserError(_('You cannot approve.'))
```

I think that employee_id.parent_id is the manager of the employee. Also please be informed that you can create a new user group

```
    <record id="group_is_manager" model="res.groups">
        <field name="name">Is a manager?</field>
    </record>
```

For the Manager users you can check this group and give this group for approve button

```
<button name="" string="" type="" groups="module_name.group_is_manager"/>
```

Hence, the button will be visible to those users who have this group.